Strange Error on upgrade corrupting menus
I updated from 5.72.1 to 5.72.2 and found that the published menu items that allow people to search from the front-end had all been corrupted. They had all been set to the default entry so anyone trying to search for a member was presented with a blank screen.
I went in and edited them to point to the correct report but now when they are selected nothing is returned.
Running Joomla 4.4.4 , PHP 8.1 and CiviCRM 5.72.2
Any clues? I'm doing some PHP traces at the moment to find out what the heck has broken again
